# Run BLS API large dataframe with results per query limit and save as dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, api, lapply, rbind

I am trying to pull a large amount of data (~500K individual series IDs) using the BLS API and store the output as a dataframe.

I've run into a two problems:

1. The BLS API only allows 50 results/query and 2.5K queries per day
2. Saving the output as a compiled dataframe

I created a dataframe with just one column "Series ID" which is the information the BLS API needs to spit back out the data on that particular ID. To bypass the results/query limit, I've tried splitting a data frame of all 500K series IDs into groups of 250 (to stay under the queries per day limit) and using a function to run the bls_api code through each group separately. I believe this may have worked, but I'm unable to see the output. To try and save the output in a dataframe, I created a blank dataframe and attempted to rbind the BLS Data function output with the blank dataframe.

## Create a blank dataframe to store BLS output in

`output <- data.frame();`

## Run BLS API code on segments of 250 lines of series IDs

```
unlist(lapply(split(df$`Series ID`, rep(1:250)),
function(Data)
{bls_data <- bls_api(Data,startyear=2016, endyear= 2019, Sys.getenv("BLS_KEY"));
output <- rbind(output,bls_data)}))
```

While I see the output of the `BLS_API (ie. "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED")` in the console, the output does not save as the dataframe "output" (the dataframe is still blank).

I'm new to functions so any advice is valuable!

Comment: I typically would save each api call result into a list and then `do.call(rbind, mylist)` to get a final output data set. Search google for `concatenating data frames in r` and there's tons of blog posts about this.

Comment: Also, this is one of those times where an explicit `for` loop is just fine. It's way more flexible and readable here and I wouldn't expect it to cause any performance hit.

Comment: I tried another version of splitting up my dataframe into a list with 
`list(split(df,as.numeric(rownames(df))-1)%/%250)`
but couldn't figure out from there the right loop that would work in the list of dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I was able to figure out. Not the most elegant solution, but gets the job done!

Define the number of rows wanted per group

```
nSegments <- 250
```

Split series IDs into segments based on the number of rows defined above

```
series_ids_split <- split(df, 
(seq(nrow(df))-1) %/% nSegments)
```

Run function for series IDs with definite data output

```
total_output <- lapply(eries_ids_split, function(x){
x <- bls_api(x,startyear = 2018, endyear = 2019, Sys.getenv("BLS_KEY"))
return(x)
})
```

Merge list of dataframes into output dataframe
`output_df <- do.call(rbind,total_output)`